# Sharing atoms between http-connected erlang clusters

Tags: erlang

We have a few non-erlang-connected clusters in our infrastructure and currently use term_to_binary to encode erlang terms for messages between the clusters. On the receiving side we use binary_to_term(Bin, [safe]) to only convert to existing atoms (should there be any in the message).

Occasionally (especially after starting a new cluster/stack), we run into the problem that there are partially known atoms encoded in the message, i.e. the sending cluster knows this atom, but the receiving does not. This can be for various reasons, most common is that the receiving node simply has not loaded a module containing some record definition. We currently employ some nasty work-arounds which basically amount to maintaining a short-ish list of potentially used atoms, but we're not quite happy with this error-prone approach.

Is there a smart way to share atoms between these clusters? Or is it recommended to not use the binary format for such purposes?

Looking forward to your insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think hard about why non-Erlang nodes are sending atom values in the first place. Most likely there is some adjustment that can be made to the protocol being used to communicate -- or most often there is simply not a real protocol defined and the actual protocol in use evolved organically over time.

Not knowing any details of the situation, there are two solutions to this:

- Go deep and use an abstract serialization technique like ASN.1 or JSON or whatever, using binary strings instead of atoms. This makes the most sense when you have a largish set of well understood, structured data to send (which may wrap unstructured or opaque data).
- Remain shallow and instead write a functional API interface for the processes/modules you will be sending to/calling first, to make sure you fully understand what your protocol actually is, and then back that up by making each interface call correspond to a matching network message which, when received, dispatches the same procedures an API function call would have.

The basic problem is the idea of non-Erlang nodes being able to generate atoms that the cluster may not be aware of. This is a somewhat sticky problem. In many cases the places where you are using atoms you can instead use binaries to similar effect and retain the same semantics without confusing the runtime. Its the difference between `{<<"new_message">>, Data}` and `{new_message, Data}`; matching within a function head works the same way, just slightly more noisy syntactically.

Comment: Thanks for your input. JSON is actually what we were using before (and what we would go back to, if we don't find a sufficient solution), but found the extra step Erlang term -> JSON -> Erlang term unnecessary, since both sides are Erlang nodes/clusters and do understand the Erlang terms already.

Comment: And to clarify: On both sides of the cluster-to-cluster communication are Erlang nodes. And currently we don't want to connect them via Erlang to a super-cluster (which would probably solve the atom knowledge issues via the distributed messaging protocol).

I do see the point of "underspecified API" though and will have another long hard look at it, but from a first confirming glance we're using clearly defined records as building blocks of our messages and just run into the problem that sometimes those records are not loaded yet (or nested elements of it).

Comment: @Christian If the traffic is from one internal to another I might consider using the "unsafe" bin to term, because you control everything. If you don't control everything I might make a header file of all records in use and include that in whatever module is loaded first on both ends. OTOH, the "right" way is to do a proper API specification, but that may be impractical for business reasons. If that is the case I think a record header file is probably the least hackish, most discoverable, and least scary (you can still do "safe" binary to term).

Comment: Sorry I ignored this so long. We ended up doing double wrapping - an outer well-defined structure that is en-/decoded safely (i.e. using only existing atoms) and an inner payload structure which is trusted to be safe thanks to the outer structure, so we decode that "unsafe".
Thanks for helping think through the issue @zxq9